# UWSGI broken pipe on uploads with load balancer

Tags: python, load-balancing, uwsgi

We have a storage service where client can upload files. The storage service is behind the load balancer. Whenever load balancer performs a healthcheck we have disconnections in the uploads. Basically broken pipe and SSL disconnection errno 32.

Our setup is as follows

CLIENT -> LOAD BALANCER -> UWSGI 1.4.5 -> STORAGE SERVICE

And when we did the same test with UWSGI 2.0 we didn't see this problem. Though our plan is to move to UWSGI 2.0, we want to currently patch the existing servers.

Does anybody know if there is particular patch or BUG that fixed this issues? Any suggestions?

Let me know if you have further questions...

Comment: which is the load balancer ? if it is a proprietary one, can you describe which kind of check it makes ?

Comment: I believe it is making an empty connection on 443 port of the storage service. It is easy to simulate with a netcat <ip address storage service> 443 < /dev/null

Comment: sorry i think i misunderstood your question, is the healtcheck that fails or currently running requests ?

Comment: Not the healthcheck. When there is a healthcheck connection from load balancer, any currently running upload request gets disconnected.